# What is the alternative for C++ opencv VideoCapture in android to grab frame from url stream?

Tags: opencv, android

I was using [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) in opencv c++ application to open video stream and now I am porting the same application to android. Android application is compiled with [OpenCV4Android SDK 2.4.11](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) version, but here the VideoCapture doesn't have constructor/open api with string argument to open url. Why is it not implemented for android? In android open takes only camera id. Is there any alternate java API for android to open a stream and grab frame or should I use native application?

Comment: Please add a comment for down voting.

Comment: I'm also wondering this--I have been able to read frames of an mp4 with VideoCapture(String filename) with opencv java on windows.  I was hoping to do the same on android.  My wild guess is that its because the android opencv platform doesn't have the ffmpeg libs needed to decode frames from videos.  Maybe opencv 3.0 android has this constructor, or will someday?

Comment: I just noticed that the javadoc for the latest opencv 3.0 android sdk has the missing VideoCapture constructor that takes a String.  I don't know if it works though, I will probably give it a try sometime in the next few weeks...